# How to add colored rectangles with textview in it

Tags: android, canvas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOXLo.png)I am developing an Android app.
Dynamically I created name (obtained from server), but now I need to add colored rectangles of same height and width and some textview in it.

I have attached the image that I need to develop.

How can I achieve this? Using canvas? I am finding it very difficult.

[image]

Comment: use textView and otherTextView in linear Layout with orientation horizontal ...

Comment: paste your xml code here

Comment: I need to have colored rectangles

Comment: share the source code you developed till now and someone of us will improve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TextView, just add padding and background to achive this :)
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    tools:context="xyz.mhuy.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HelloWorld"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:gravity=""/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Above Is what you mean? the result is:
[image]

Comment: Does this create a colored rectangle with textview of black color in it?

Comment: I am having a problem... The textview with 'next' and red color is appearing but it is slighlty going in the action bar and is not exactly beside the 'Hello World'

Comment: Pls screenshot your problem and the result you want to  :)

Comment: Ok i have added new image.. There is gap between 2 textviews represented by white color. I want something that is there in the original pic which I posted first. How do I do this? :)

Comment: I think you should post full of XML that I can easily figure out your problems :)